# SVG fill-opacity equivalent for IE8 VML

Tags: css, vml

The fill-opacity selector doesn't seem to work in IE8. Does anyone know how to make VML shapes in IE8 semi-transparent?

Comment: I thought IE8 didn't support SVG at all... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353798/svg-support-for-internet-explorer-8-and-below

Comment: @BigBadaboom you're right, it's vml. Editing my answer.

Comment: Have you considered using a library like Raphael, which supports both SVG and VML?

Comment: @Spudley currently using Raphael. There are callback functions in the VML that set CSS for the shapes. It's in there I'm trying to set transparency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to leave well-enough alone. If IE8 refuses to accept SVGs, then user's will have to use the uglier VML experience :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like setting the `opacity` attribute to the `v:fill` element ?

```
var vfill = document.createElement("v:fill");
vfill.setAttribute("color",fillcolor);
vfill.setAttribute("opacity",fillopacity);
```

Source

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229612(v=vs.85).aspx