# Access to svg through jquery in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-8

I am looking for a way to use jquery to manipulate SVG paths in IE8, currently I am using the following syntax and works fine in IE9+

```
$('svg path.someClass').css({fill:'rgb(0,0,0)'});
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353798/svg-support-for-internet-explorer-8-and-below

Answer (score 1):

As IE8 [doesn't support SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg), I'd say no, you can't do that. You could possibly make IE8 at least understand that the SVG elements were elements (by using the `createElement` trick in the `head` that people use for HTML5 elements so it at least doesn't think they're completely alien), but they won't be displayed properly, so manipulating them probably doesn't make much sense.