# Svg Tag Not working In IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have created Svg country footprint map.its Working Well all Google chrome and Mozilla Firebox.Finally when run my code browser internet explorer  working well above version IE 9+  all working.But Not at all working Below version of Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 7.how to fix my error ?how to run my code in IE8?

Comment: There is no built-in svg support in ie8 and previous releases. However, maybe some of [these SO suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9355982) are helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed my issues i using jvector map its working well in Ie8 browser..thank for all comments

Comment: hi can you brief how you used jvector map for svg. I am using pie chart to create the charts dynamically and displaying it. other than ie8 its working fine. If you know how to display chart in IE8 let me know. Thank you