# Crossbrowser svg donut chart

Tags: svg, charts, d3.js

I'm playing around with the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KsFPh/
It uses d3 and SVG to render the donut chart

```
var vis = d3.select("#pie-chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);
```

What would I need to apply/include to make this work in IE 7 and 8?
Currently it works in IE9. Is Raphael an option or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

Those versions of IE do not support SVG. You could try something like https://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/. See the accepted answer to [Can't display SVG charts in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6097246/173225) for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [g.raphael.js](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) perhaps? See http://matthewodette.com/graphael-donut-charts/ for an example.

There's also the [r2d3 shim](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3) if you want to use [d3.js](http://d3js.org) but need it to work in older IE versions too.