# How to remove annotation tick mark in line chart of google api chart?

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-api, google-visualization

I got this chart in line chart of google api.

[image]

Here i'm trying to display the point value in above the point. so i'm using annotation. Here how to remove annotation tick mark in between the points(23 & 2008, 145 & 2009...) in google api chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Year');                
            data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'}); 
            data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

            data.addRows([
                ['2008', 23, 54],
                ['2009', 145, 55],
                ['2010', 245, 56],
                ['2011', 350, 57]
            ]);               
            var options = {
                width: 400,
                height: 200,
                pointSize: 4,
                legend: {position: 'none'},
                chartArea: {
                    left: 0,
                    top: 60,                        
                    width: 400,
                    height: 50},
                vAxis: {
                    baselineColor: '#fff',
                    gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},                        
                        maxValue:'58',
                        minValue:'52'                                  
                },                    
                tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
                annotation: {
                    1: {
                        style: 'default'

                    }                                             
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to do that using API.

Those 4 ticks are presented as SVG elements:

```
<g>
    <rect x="50.375" y="105" width="1" height="5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect>
    <rect x="150.125" y="105" width="1" height="5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect>
    <rect x="249.875" y="105" width="1" height="5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect>
    <rect x="349.625" y="105" width="1" height="5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#999999"></rect>
</g>
```

and there is nothing special to hook on to change it. Using for example CSS rule `display: none`

You can do something like this:

```
var rectTags = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");

function drawChart() {
   ...

    chart.draw(data, options);

    for (var i = 0; i < rectTags.length; i++) {
        if (rectTags[i].hasAttribute("width")) {
            var width = rectTags[i].getAttribute("width");
            if (parseInt(width) == 1) {
                rectTags[i].setAttribute("width", 0);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

[image: chart without ticks]

But you can use this solution only in case you have no other `rect` elements with `width` 1. So, you can do additional check if `rectTags` is the same as number of data raws.

See [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/eZiqAxiW/1/)

This example uses SVG and it won't work with IE7/IE8. See [Can't display SVG charts in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097179/cant-display-svg-charts-in-internet-explorer-8/6097246)

Comment: @Hariprasath I added example at jsBin. `for` loop should be put immediately after `chart.draw(data, options);`

Comment: but for me the rectTags length is 0 for the same code. but im using pie chart and bar chart in the same page

Comment: Your code is different and most probably also resulting svg markup. Could you post your code somewhere to see it.

Comment: @Hariprasath: I don't know. Anyway this solution is a hack and I wouldn't use it if I was not sure that I would spoil something. Because of that I wrote _But you can use this solution only in case you have no other rect elements with width 1_. If I have "limited" example, I will use it but not in some complex chart where  I could hide other elements.

Answer (score 30):

You can remove the annotation tick marks or 'stems' by setting the `stemColor` parameter to none:

```
annotations: {
   stemColor : 'none'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @badhairut, this is actually the right answer, simple and clean.