# Calculate dimentions of SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How to calculate the dimensions of a SVG element in a consistent way, cross browser ?

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var gBCR = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var bBox = svg.getBBox().width;
var gCS = window.getComputedStyle(svg, null).width;
console.log('gBCR: ' + Math.round(gBCR) + ' - gCS: ' + gCS + ' - bBox: ' + Math.round(bBox));

// What I got:
// Firefox: gBCR: 142 - gCS: 400px - bBox: 363
// Chrome:  gBCR: 400 - gCS: 400px - bBox: 363
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/23x8S/

My svg element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="200px">
    <title>HTML5 Logo</title>
    <polygon fill="#E44D26" points="107.644,470.877 74.633,100.62 437.367,100.62 404.321,470.819 255.778,512" />
    <polygon fill="#F16529" points="256,480.523 376.03,447.246 404.27,130.894 256,130.894             " />
    <polygon fill="#EBEBEB" points="256,268.217 195.91,268.217 191.76,221.716 256,221.716 256,176.305 255.843,176.305 142.132,176.305 143.219,188.488 154.38,313.627 256,313.627" />
    <polygon fill="#EBEBEB" points="256,386.153 255.801,386.206 205.227,372.55 201.994,336.333 177.419,336.333 156.409,336.333 162.771,407.634 255.791,433.457 256,433.399" />
    <path d="M108.382,0h23.077v22.8h21.11V0h23.078v69.044H152.57v-23.12h-21.11v23.12h-23.077V0z" />
    <path d="M205.994,22.896h-20.316V0h63.72v22.896h-20.325v46.148h-23.078V22.896z" />
    <path d="M259.511,0h24.063l14.802,24.26L313.163,0h24.072v69.044h-22.982V34.822l-15.877,24.549h-0.397l-15.888-24.549v34.222h-22.58V0z" />
    <path d="M348.72,0h23.084v46.222h32.453v22.822H348.72V0z" />
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="255.843,268.217 255.843,313.627 311.761,313.627 306.49,372.521 255.843,386.191 255.843,433.435 348.937,407.634 349.62,399.962 360.291,280.411 361.399,268.217 349.162,268.217" />
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="255.843,176.305 255.843,204.509 255.843,221.605 255.843,221.716 365.385,221.716 365.385,221.716 365.531,221.716 366.442,211.509 368.511,188.488 369.597,176.305" />
<svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach seems right, It gives the right width in both cases, the problem is that the `SVG` component is rendered different in Firefox and Chrome, in Chrome use the 100% of available width and in Firefox use the minimum width to display the content.

This tracker explains why Firefox are not using "100%" as default width: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=611099

Comment: Roberto, thank you for checking this out. What would be the right way to get the same number out of this? If I force the width of the SVG element to be `width="400px"` the problem still exists, now in a proporcional way to the first one: http://jsfiddle.net/2zn32/1/

Comment: Not only 100% width, but 100% height as well. Fixing both width and height (aspect ratio matching the viewport dimensions): http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/WDQ6X/2/

Comment: @Sergio, If you can use jQuery, using `$('svg').width()` returns 400 in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @Roberto, that was a nice pointer. jQuery uses `.getComputedStyle`. Updated my question width that info. Now just have to find a way to get consistent results in older browsers. Btw, just tested IE8 and jQuery returns `0` there...

Comment: Does IE8 support SVG ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097179/cant-display-svg-charts-in-internet-explorer-8/6097246#6097246, do you get to display correctly the logo ?, unfortunately I have not any IE8 browser to test it on.